# Set cell value when editing another cell

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157860/javafx-tableview-set-cell-value-when-editing-another-cell) but I can't see the answer pretty clear.

What I'm trying to do is to get the value inside a cell from a TableColumn calculated when I insert a value into another cell...

[image: Calculate difference]

A tiny piece of the code.

```
colExistenciaF.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    colExistenciaF.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Productos, Double>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Productos, Double> event) {
            event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    .setExistencia(event.getNewValue());

            // Code to place the calculated value in that other column
        }
    });
```

An observation, my "Existencia Actual" column is declared this way:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Productos, Double> colExistenciaI;
```

And the "Existencia Actual" and "Diferencia" columns this one:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Productos, Double> colExistenciaF;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Movproductos, Double> colDiferencia;
```

This is because I have and entity that stores the initial inventory (Producto.class) or existence of a product, but when I need to make a transaction or movement I use another entity (MovProducto.class). I don't if this is relevant but had to mention just in case you need a little more of context.

## Edit

---

To give you more context, I'm working with hibernate, so my pojos classes can't use (as I know) StringProperty or any kind of data type that is not present in the database.

These are my pojos to use in this issue:

- [Product](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/e87e9c9c124726547247ff9dc1694310)
- [Product Transaction](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/3a43c39d75decd36c9b8ee560645de37)

These are my controllers (ingore the bad name of the class DAO)

- [View Controller](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/8ee8abb3b2185ea2bec4fc5ac179b4fc)
- [Transaction "DAO"](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/b240140e3e61690eabe899d85d689c8b)
- [ProductTransaction "DAO"](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/dfc22b92d2a4536c4d53addde82806d2)

Finally the [database](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/75ed00669d862ef16d4e72d63f659b49) and the [FXML file](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/1a40b1e52c239b8cff80732a3fb7b0ca)

---

Thank you in advance Dr. James_D. :)

Comment: "I'm working with hibernate, so my pojos classes can't use (as I know) StringProperty" is not true. See, e.g. http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa

Comment: @James_D sorry, I didn't wanted to make such an statement, I was trying to say that as far as I know, working on that. thanks again.

Comment: @James_D doing what you say, and following your example [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453), I encountered with another problem, it's about hibernate mapping annotations I think, `Error when trying to map a Set type object` I've created [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817905/error-when-trying-to-map-a-set-type-object-property-access-method-and-jpa-annot) question for that problem but still can't find the solution. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: Yessssss. I saw that. I haven't worked with hibernate and collections with JavaFX properties at the same time. If I have time later I'll see if I can figure out a solution...

Comment: @James_D Thank you! I uploaded the practice project to github, if you feel like giving a look [here is it](https://github.com/ajfmo/inventario/tree/master/Inventario).

Comment: @James_D Hi! I have already solve the error with the mappings, I had the annotation in the wrong place (not at the getter method), so **that** error is solved, now I have anothers... Working on solving them... I will accept the answer after implementing properly your suggestions.

Comment: @James_D Hi! hope you're fine. I had tried to solve this task without success, I'm a little embarrassed for the fact I haven't found a solution yet, I dont wan't to bother you, but can you please lend me a hand with task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

#### Steps:

1. Use property access instead field access. See this [post](http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa) for more info, you can also use [this gists](https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453) as example.
2. Once step 1 is done you can use this code in your column that needs to be calculated (adapt the code to your needs). I got the idea from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178479/javafx-tableview-update-cell-after-editing-another-cell-of-the-same-row).

   ```
       colDiferencia.setCellValueFactory((cellData) -> {
       cellData.getValue().DiferenciaExistenciaProperty()
               .bind(cellData.getValue().ProductosExistenciaActual().subtract(
                       Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(cellData.getValue().ProductosExistenciaInicialProperty()))));
       return cellData.getValue().DiferenciaExistenciaProperty().asObject();
   });

   colExistenciaF.setCellFactory((d) -> {
       TableCell<Productos, Double> cell = new TableCell<Productos, Double>() {
           @Override
           protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
               super.updateItem(item, empty);
               setText(String.valueOf(item));
           }

       };
       return cell;
   });
   ```

With this method you will solve the issue, but I'm pretty sure that just like me, you will get some other errors or questions.

By now I can close this question, bot before thanking all the people involve.

Thanks a lot <3 *.* @James_D and @Sunflame I hope you see my practice project and help me improve more hehe! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example you can check.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Model> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, Double> initial;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, Double> actual;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, Double> diff;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        initial.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().initialProperty().asObject());
        actual.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().actualProperty().asObject());
        diff.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().differenceProperty().asObject());

        initial.setCellFactory(factory -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DoubleConverter()));
        actual.setCellFactory(factory -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(new DoubleConverter()));

        table.setEditable(true);
        diff.setEditable(false); // I think it makes sense to set non-editable

        ObservableList<Model> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        data.add(new Model(10D, 9D));
        data.add(new Model(98D, 45D));

        table.setItems(data);
    }

    class Model {

        private DoubleProperty initial;
        private DoubleProperty actual;
        private DoubleProperty difference;

        public Model(Double initial, Double actual) {
            this.initial = new SimpleDoubleProperty(initial);
            this.actual = new SimpleDoubleProperty(actual);
            this.difference = new SimpleDoubleProperty(initial - actual);
            // Here is where the "magic" happens :)
            this.difference.bind(this.initial.subtract(this.actual));
        }

        public double getInitial() {
            return initial.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty initialProperty() {
            return initial;
        }

        public double getActual() {
            return actual.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty actualProperty() {
            return actual;
        }

        public double getDifference() {
            return difference.get();
        }

        public DoubleProperty differenceProperty() {
            return difference;
        }
    }

    class DoubleConverter extends StringConverter<Double> {

        @Override
        public String toString(Double object) {
            return object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Double fromString(String string) {
            return Double.valueOf(string);
        }
    }

}
```

Of course you can handle a few things there like `NumberformatException`. But that you want to solve I think it works.

Comment: I should have place more code to give more context, as I'm trying (**trying really hard**) to get your solution, I think it's not the approach I need and this is why: 

My model or entities are made up of String and double fields, since I'm using hibernate and as I have seen so far, entities pojos should have those types of fields (String, double, int). 

So I'm placing more code to the question.

Thank you pretty much, I hope you can help me.

Comment: I think that is a really bad practice to use your pojos as the Model in the UI. U can simply create a model for your `TableView` then pass the fields of your pjos to its constructor then you have separated easily the pojos and the UI model, and it solves this problem too.

Comment: Got it, this is my task to do today, I will do it with another project I've created but smaller to dominate the concepts, anyway if is there another way to achieve what I'm looking for I would like to know.

Comment: There's no reason not to use JavaFX properties in JPA entities; just make sure you are using "property access" instead of "field access"; i.e. annotate the `getXXX` methods, not the fields. In this simple example you would only have database columns for `initial` and `actual`, presumably, so `difference` would be annotated as `@Transient`.

Comment: You should probably expose a `ReadOnlyDoubleProperty` for  `difference`, since it is bound (you want to avoid client code calling `differenceProperty().set(...)`, for example).

Comment: @James_D I have just found this! [Example of JPA entities that use JavaFX properties.](https://gist.github.com/james-d/e485ac525c71e20bb453) and guess whos the author!

Comment: @Sunflame Hi! I have tried with your suggestion but still can't make it work, would you like to see my code in [practice project](https://github.com/ajfmo/inventario/) for further help please?

Comment: Which part is not working? You don't get the correct value, or you don't get any value? In `Productos` if you are using the binding for `precioProducto`, then the line 45 is useless since the value is updated based on those two properties. Then you can simply initialize it, without setting an initial value. After that the update should work based on that binding.I see you are setting as initial value some king of percentage(?). Are you expecting a percentage there ? Then you should modify that binding to represent that calculation.

Comment: @Sunflame Hi! thanks for the answer, I don't get the correct value, theres a column called "utilidad" that represent the profit of the product this is the calculation that usually is done: price= cost/(profit-100)/100, I would like to know how to make that calc, **but** this exact issue has nothing to do with the question posted originally If you like you can ask to contribute at my practice project and point me the error making an issue, just if you want to, tho I would really appreciate that. As for the question I found the solution and I'm posting the answer. Thanks a lot!