# Error when trying to map a Set type object (Property access method and JPA annotation) not duplicated tho

Tags: jpa, javafx, annotations, javafx-8

In order to accomplish another task, I need redefine my pojos classes and use property access to take advantage of JavaFX properties in my mentioned classes, but I'm facing this error.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: deposito, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(productoses)]
```

I have already tryied the solutions mentioned in [org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164123/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-set) and [org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774198/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-determine-type-for-java-util-list-at) but still can't make it work.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/a8cb56272597dd07e583019701ea7e03) is my OneToMany entity class and [here](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/0ca285e1e755f3178c1d32b4600d56fe) is my ManyToOne class.

And this is the stacktrace.

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: deposito, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(productoses)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.buildSessionFactory(MetadataImpl.java:170)
    at ajfmo.inventario.utils.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at ajfmo.inventario.DAO.ProductDAO.<init>(ProductDAO.java:20)
    at ajfmo.inventario.view.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:60)
```

## Edit

---

[This](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/15cdc4bed75f6d3adc19511aa5ee783d) is my HibernateUtil class. [This](https://gist.github.com/ajfmo/ead82710b05755131668b48d49a2bfde) one is the DAO that appears in the stack trace.

---

Thank you in advance, this is my first project using hibernate... Or my first project at all indeed.

Comment: So looking at the stack trace the problem seems to be inside the `HibernateUtil` class. It is invoked by the `ProductDAO`class, which is invoked by the `MainView` class. You should post those instead of the classes you posted. This would help a lot. Also take at look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people solve your problem.

Comment: @MarkusK thanks for your comment. I edited the posts and added those two clasess, but I dont think the problem comes from there, I think is the annotation but still haven't found a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Deposito` class I see that your JPA annotation is on the property and not on the getter like everywhere else in the class (I doubt this is your problem, but maybe a good idea to be consistent)

And here you have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "deposito")
private Set<Productos> productoses = new HashSet<Productos>(0);

public Set<Productos> getProductoses() {
  return this.productoses;
}
```

In the `Productos` class you have:

```
private ObjectProperty<Deposito> deposito;
private Deposito _deposito;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "deposito_producto", referencedColumnName = "descripcion_deposito", nullable = false)
public Deposito getDeposito() {
  if (deposito == null) {
    return _deposito;
  } else {
    return deposito.get();
  }
}
```

`referencedColumnName = "descripcion_deposito"` point to this method (which is probably not the one you intended):

```
@Column(name = "descripcion_deposito", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getDescripcionDeposito() {
  if (descripcionDeposito == null) {
    return _descripcionDeposito;
  } else {
    return descripcionDeposito.get();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what your column names are, but the `referencedColumnName` should point to the primary/foreign key of the  field of the `Productos` object, try this in the `Productos` class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "deposito_producto", referencedColumnName = "idDeposito", nullable = false)
public Deposito getDeposito() {
  if (deposito == null) {
    return _deposito;
  } else {
    return deposito.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: @nicolschl Thank you very much! indeed the problem was the misplacing of the annotation. To clarify your doubt just in case, "producto" obviusly is product and "deposito" is warehouse, many products have one warehouse, one warehouse have many products, in my product's table there is a varchar column called "deposito_productos" this a FK of "descripcion_deposito", I found this way a little more easy when it comes to retrieve data, not pretty sure but so far for what I need it works fine, I know that in a future I'll have to do this kind of relationships using the primary/foreign keys. 10x!